# Хочу реализовать функцию одноразового бота для вк

Tags: python

Пользователь пишет сообщение и участвует в розыгрыше. Если розыгрыш успешен, то пользователя заносят в определнный список и если пользователь еще раз вызовет бота командой то бот не должен отвечать. Хотел спросить - это лучше сделать через дб или можно оставить файл с id?

Comment: Обязательно всегда хранить список участников где-то вне? Мб при запуске бота загружать список из файла, в ходе работы добавлять пользователь в список, при завершении работы записывать список опять в файл.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Это придётся загружать строки из файла в массив? Подскажи как лучше сделать проверку на совпадение айди. Моя функция всегда выдаёт что данного юзера нет в списке и получается что юзер может писать бесконечно

Comment: Спосов сериализации и десериализации много. Думаю, в вашем случае подойдёт просто чтение строк из файла. Проверить наличие id в списке: `if id in id_list:`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!